# Private modules npm install error

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-modules

After `npm install` in project local directory I've got log with error like this

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "..{path}" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/home/.npm/_logs/2018-06-28T11_13_56_437Z-debug.log
```

How I can resolve this problem? (the best way without deleting node-modules)

Comment: All is done with another package manager yarn